# Getting object type after serialization in groovy/grails

Tags: grails, serialization, web, groovy

Hey guys I would appreciate it if you could help me. First of all excuse my English and secondly I would try my best to describe the problem.

As far as I know after a submitToRemote in grails the form parameters are serialized and then submitted. Now the problem:
Between two GSP pages I'm trying to send an `ArrayList<foo>` back and forth. To save it on each page I'm using `<g:hiddenField>` which is then used in the controller using params. When the the form is submitted the controller can no longer use the arrayList because it is of type string. 
Also I am to do this without using cookies or sessions.

Any ideas as to how to convert to de-serialize the arrayList after the submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that's a simple `ArrayList<Integer>` you can use the method `list()` of `params`.

```
def myList = params.list('myList') //myList is the name in the view.
```

If it's a more complex list, like a list of one domain class, then you need to use commands.

```
Class A {
  String name
}

Class ACommand {
  List<A> listA = ListUtils.lazyList( [], FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(A) )
}
```

**View**

```
<g:hiddenField name="listA[0].name" value="Fisrt Name" />
<g:hiddenField name="listA[1].name" value="Second Name" />
```

**Binding the Command**

```
class MyController {
  def someAction() {
    //in this example assume that this action is called in the submit of the form
    ACommand command = new ACommand()
    bindData(command, params) //this will populate the command with your list
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the second suggestion with the command could be my solution. However, Im using a ArrayList containing a domain object but in the hidden fields im not storing certain values in the list, im storing the entire list. <g:hiddenField name="theName" value="ExampleArrayList"/> @Sérgio Michels

Comment: Well, then you will need to manually set your list. But I recommend the command in this cases.

Comment: Isn't there a way to still use the command but with a <g:hiddenField name="theList" value="listA" /> instead of <g:hiddenField name="theList" value="listA[0]" /> ?

Comment: Also why do you put the name of the hiddenField equal to the list value, shouldn't the value be equal to the list value and name equal to the field in the domain object?

Comment: listA is my field in the command. Name is the attribute in the domain class and value is the value that the name will have. Try to use params.list('theName') and check if the list is populated correctly (without command).

Comment: Still no luck, i have tried the params.list('theName') but it returns an ArrayList with the "theName" as a string in slot [0].

Comment: So try the command approach, or update your question with the reproducible code of  your problem.